# Mocking concrete class

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito

I am unit testing a Presenter class which connects to service and returns a token 
When user receives a token from Async task which calls REst services, Home screen starts. If token is null error is shown

```
public void onSignInButtonClicked() {

    String username = mSigninView.getUsername();


    if (username.isEmpty()) {
        mSigninView.showUsernameError(R.string.username_error);
        return;
    }

    String password = mSigninView.getPassword();
    if (password.isEmpty()) {
        mSigninView.showPasswordError(R.string.password_error);
        return;
    }

    String token = mSigninService.connectToRestServices(username, password);
    if (token != null) {
        mSigninView.startHomeActivity(token);
    } else {
        mSigninView.showLoginError(R.string.login_error);
    }
}
```

For unit testing :

```
@Test
public void shouldStartHomeScreenWhenUsernameAndPasswordAreCorrect() throws Exception {
    Mockito.when(mView.getUsername()).thenReturn("test@test.com");
    Mockito.when(mView.getPassword()).thenReturn("test");
    Mockito.when(mService.connectToRestServices("test@test.com", "test")).thenReturn("test");
    mPresenter.onSignInButtonClicked();
    Mockito.verify(mView).startHomeActivity("test");
}
```

Error while testing

Wanted but not invoked:
signin_View.startHomeActivity("test");
-> at com.ssd.cypress.uimobile.SigninPresenterTest.shouldStartHomeScreenWhenUsernameAndPasswordAreCorrect(SigninPresenterTest.java:72)

In the code 
String token = mSigninService.connectToRestServices(username, password);
It connects to concrete class and token is null. Is there a way to mock this connectToService so that  it returns SomeValue.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your token isn't null and it tries to execute startHomeActivity("test"). So it does return "SomeValue". Try executing the unit test in debug mode and see what exactly is the value of token that you get before a null comparison is made.

Comment: thanks for your response!!! The token is always null. In my code the constructor for the presenter is

Comment: public SigninPresenter(Signin_View view) {
        mSigninView = view;
        mSigninService = new Sign_in_service();
    }

Comment: Here when presenter is mocked, it creates a new service object which i cannot control. This app is written as MVP pattern where service is initialized in the Presenter layer. This object returns token always null.

Comment: Please if you can tell me how to unit test Presenter class when the constructor is like above?

Comment: Your mock of mService.connectToRestServices() does return "test". Just put a sysout after that statement to verify: System.out.println(mService.connectToRestServices("test@gmail.com", "test")); 

Ideally, you should be mocking the startHomeActivity() method also in the same test because your unit test is on the onSignInButtonClicked() and not on the startHomeActivity(). So you should assume all other invocations inside onSignInButtonClicked() are mocked and they execute and return success. You should write a separate unit test to verify the logic for startHomeActivity().

Answer (score 0):

Your mock service collaborator `mService` is never called during the test because it's not passed into or injected into the class under test.  Based on your comments, I think you realize this.

To restate your comments as I understand them, you want to use the mock of a collaborator - an instance of `Sign_in_service` -  but you can't do it because the collaborator is created by rather than passed into your class under test -  `SigninPresenter`.

The problem is your constructor of `SigninPresenter`, which should not be responsible for creating a collaborator.  It seems like you own the code in question, so you can change the design.

I suggest you replace the `SigninPresenter` constructor with the following:

```
    public static SigninPresenter createSigninPresenterWithService(Signin_View view) {
        return new SigninPresenter(view,  new Sign_in_service());
    }

    protected SigninPresenter(Signin_View view, Sign_in_service service) { 
        mSigninView = view; 
        mSigninService = service; 
    }
```

For your test, you can call the constructor and pass in a mock of the service to initialize `mPresenter`, that is: `mPresenter = new SignInPresenter(mView, mService)`.  In your production code which currently calls the constructor of `SigninPresenter`, you can replace the constructor call `new SigninPresenter(view)` with a call to the static factory method `createSigninPresenterWithService(view)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. Works for me.

Comment: You're welcome. In that case, please select my answer as the solution to your issue by clicking on the check mark on the left.